# Android background service Cordova plugin to Monitor Beacons

Tags: android-service, cordova-plugins, ibeacon, altbeacon

**UPDATE:**

*I got it working on a different phone. I don't know if the issue is with the library or the phone or Android version. The phone it is failing on is BLU ADVANCE 4.0 L2 running Android 6.0. I tested it on other phone which is running Android 5.1 and it works fine on that. Can someone explain why that might be happening?*

I created a basic background service plugin that would Monitor for beacons on Android when the app is killed. I am running into a strange issue. Beacon monitoring works fine when my app is in background/foreground, **when I kill the app my service keeps running but the beacon monitoring stops working!** Monitoring starts working again as soon as I open my next time. I am using Altbeacon library. I noticed that as soon as I kill the app, beaconManager becomes null, and it doesn't bind again until you start the app.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand run");

    initialiseService();

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this.getApplicationContext());
    // To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon
    // type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(_beaconLayout));
    beaconManager.bind(this);

    return START_STICKY;  
}
```

I start monitoring inside OnBeaconServiceConnect()

```
@Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        isInitialized = true;
        lastMessage = "Beacon Service Connected";
        send();
        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {

            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                lastMessage = "I just saw an beacon for the first time!";
                //sendMessage();
                send();
                Log.i(TAG, lastMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                lastMessage = "I no longer see an beacon";
                //sendMessage();
                send();
                Log.i(TAG, lastMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
                lastMessage = "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state;
                Log.i(TAG, lastMessage);
            }
        });

        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    //send();
                    Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {    }

    }
```

This is the another plugin I tried using - [github.com/lulibrary/Background-Beacon-Monitoring](http://github.com/lulibrary/Background-Beacon-Monitoring) I am seeing the same behavior with this plugin also. After I kill the app the Service restarts and the beaconManager doesn't bind.

Here is my Android Manifest below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.example.sample" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="uk.ac.lancaster.library.backgroundbeacons.StartupBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:isolatedProcess="false" android:label="myJourneysBackgroundBeaconService" android:name="uk.ac.lancaster.library.backgroundbeacons.BackgroundBeaconService" />
        <receiver android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.StartupBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:isolatedProcess="false" android:label="iBeacon" android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService" />
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor">
            <meta-data android:name="background" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="com.unarin.cordova.beacon.IBeaconPlugin.DID_RANGING" />
                <action android:name="com.unarin.cordova.beacon.IBeaconPlugin.DID_MONITORING" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: It is hard to say what could be going wrong without seeing a larger snippet of code showing how the background service plugin is set up.

Comment: This is the other background service plugin that I tried using today. Same behavior! The Service keeps running when I kill the app but Monitoring stops working. It works fine in background and foreground. This is the link to the plugin: https://github.com/lulibrary/Background-Beacon-Monitoring .. I am wondering if it's phone/Android version specific? It's the same behavior I am seeing using 2 different plugins.

Comment: You are starting your service Sticky? Where do you start monitoring? Inside your service's onCreate or inside your app? You can also try this library which I helped develop: https://github.com/inthepocket/ibeacon-scanner-android. When your app stops being active, your service gets restarted, so you have to start monitoring again in your service.

Comment: Where are you calling bind()?  Are you doing this in your service code on startup?  Are you sure it is getting called?

Comment: Elias, @davidgyoung yes, I am starting my service Sticky, and I start monitoring inside OnBeaconServiceConnect() as shown above. I am calling bind in onStartCommand(). I noticed that the service restarts when I kill the app, but the OnBeaconServiceConnect is not called when the service restarts after killing the app.

Comment: @Elias , I am able to make it work using your library. The Service restarts and beacon monitoring works even after I kill the app. Looks like its some issue with the Altbeacon library version I am using..I think I am using it correctly.

Comment: Do you see the ` Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand run"); log line on restart?

Comment: @davidyoung yes, the code in that block is executed. I also have a REST call after this line beaconmanager.bind(this) , and that is executed as well.But OnBeaconServiceConnect() is never called. I tried different versions of Altbeacon library as well but that didn't help either. I am going to try run it on a different Android phone and see if it's platform/version related.

Comment: @davidgyoung I got it working on a different phone. I don't know if the issue is with the library or the phone. The phone it is failing on is BLU ADVANCE 4.0 L2 running Android 6.0. I tested it on other phone which is running Android 5.1 and it works fine on that. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Strange.  I suspect it is some subtle different about services in 6.0, but it isn't clear what.  The lifecycle is a bit complex having two services and a force kill and restart mechanisms going.